# How to provide custom gradient in TensorFlow

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I am trying to understand that how to use `@tf.custom_gradient`  function available in TensorFlow 1.7 for providing a custom gradient of a vector with respect to a vector. Below code is the minimum working example which solves following problem to get `dz/dx`.

y=Ax
z=||y||<sup>2</sup>

[Also, this attached image describes the solution as expected by manually calulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smTd0.png)

If I do not use the `@tf.custom_gradient` then the TensorFlow gives the desired solution as expected. My question is that how can I provide custom gradient for y=Ax? We know that `dy/dx = A^T` as shown in the above attachment which shows steps of calculation that matches the TensorFlow output.

```
import tensorflow as tf

#I want to write custom gradient for this function f1
def f1(A,x):
    y=tf.matmul(A,x,name='y')
    return y

#for y= Ax, the derivative is: dy/dx= transpose(A)
@tf.custom_gradient
def f2(A,x):
    y=f1(A,x)
    def grad(dzByDy): # dz/dy = 2y reaches here correctly.
        dzByDx=tf.matmul(A,dzByDy,transpose_a=True) 
        return dzByDx
    return y,grad


x= tf.constant([[1.],[0.]],name='x')
A= tf.constant([ [1., 2.], [3., 4.]],name='A')

y=f1(A,x) # This works as desired
#y=f2(A,x) #This line gives Error


z=tf.reduce_sum(y*y,name='z')

g=tf.gradients(ys=z,xs=x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run(g)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your function `f2()` has two inputs, you have to provide a gradient to flow back to each of them. The error you see:

> Num gradients 2 generated for op name: "IdentityN" [...]  do not match num inputs 3

is admittedly quite cryptic, though. Supposing you never want to calculate d***y***/d***A***, you can just return None, dzByDx. The code below (tested):

```
import tensorflow as tf

#I want to write custom gradient for this function f1
def f1(A,x):
    y=tf.matmul(A,x,name='y')
    return y

#for y= Ax, the derivative is: dy/dx= transpose(A)
@tf.custom_gradient
def f2(A,x):
    y=f1(A,x)
    def grad(dzByDy): # dz/dy = 2y reaches here correctly.
        dzByDx=tf.matmul(A,dzByDy,transpose_a=True) 
        return None, dzByDx
    return y,grad

x= tf.constant([[1.],[0.]],name='x')
A= tf.constant([ [1., 2.], [3., 4.]],name='A')

#y=f1(A,x) # This works as desired
y=f2(A,x) #This line gives Error

z=tf.reduce_sum(y*y,name='z')

g=tf.gradients(ys=z,xs=x)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print sess.run( g )
```

outputs:

> [array([[20.],
>          [28.]], dtype=float32)]

as desired.

Comment: Sure, I'm happy to help! :)